# How to color second words in blue with matlab-prettifier

Tags: color, listings, matlab-prettifier

I'm using the [Matlab-prettifier package](https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/matlab-prettifier/matlab-prettifier.pdf) quite happy with it. Even if it can mimic almost perfectly the Matlab style it just doesn't color second words in blue (like MATLAB does). Somebody know how to manipulate it?

Here is my code vaguely:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]
>>  syms x 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

(actually that 'x' should be blue)

Comment: *Automatic highlighting of unquoted strings* is a known missing feature. See section 10 of the documentation for a workaround.